# Post with JObject Parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net, http-post, restful-url

I need to call a Post method defined in a Controller, which has a JObject Parameter.

I'm getting a 500 Error code When I call this method with PostAsJsonAsync or PostAsync.

The code below shows how I'm calling this Post Method:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{ 
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:54810");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var jsonObject = new JObject();
dynamic json = jsonObject; 
json.Add("mytoken", "teste");

json.eventos = new JArray() as dynamic;

dynamic evento = new JObject();
evento.ID = 1;
evento.Latitude = 50;
evento.Longitude = 20;
evento.Local = 30;

json.eventos.Add(evento);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/eventocontrole", jsonObject);
```

The ***response.IsSuccessStatusCode*** property is returning false.

If I change this parameter type from JObject to any other custom class (eg. User, Product, Cart), the property **IsSuccessStatusCode** returns **true**!

Am I using JObject incorrectly? Should I not use JObject as parameter?

Just to clarify, I'm using JObject because I need to pass a list of objects and a token string to validate my request.

Comment: Are you sure the data signature you are creating with JObject matches what the server is expecting? Check the actual data going over the wire (you did this already but you haven't shown the endpoint signature). I would also check the actual error message that is returned from the server - if you use Fiddler and are running in debug mode you should get more error information in the MVC/WebApi error message (yellow screen of death most likely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not to use JObject like parameter.

After many tests, the only solution was to create a custom class

```
public class RequestData<T>
{
    public T data { get; set; }
    public string token { get; set; }
}
```

My test below is calling this server method:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{ 
  client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:54810");
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

  List<EventoControle> eventos = new List<EventoControle>();

  EventoControle evento = new EventoControle();
  evento.ID = 1;
  evento.Latitude = 50;
  evento.Longitude = 20;    
  evento.Local = 30;

  eventos.Add(evento); 

  RequestData<List<EventoControle>> rq = new RequestData<List<EventoControle>>();
  rq.data = eventos;
  rq.token = "teste";

  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<RequestData<List<EventoControle>>>("api/eventocontrole", rq);
  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
  }                                   
}
```

My server method:

```
public void PostEventoControle(RequestData<List<EventoControle>> json)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try sending the serialized data as `StringContent`:

```
string jsonData = jsonObject.ToString();
var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/eventocontrole", content);
```

Comment: Have you verified that `jsonData` contains the expected JSON string? Also you can use Fiddler to check the actual HTTP payload being sent to the server. Debugging the server endpoint against this HTTP request might also reveal more information about the possible error being thrown.

Comment: {
  "mytoken": "teste",
  "eventos": [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "Latitude": 50,
      "Longitude": 20,
      "Local": 30
    }
  ]
}

Comment: great, seems like the correct payload. Have you verified that the `Content-Type: application/json` request header is being set? If this is true, then you might need to debug your server side code to see why it fails as the request seems fine. It appears that the problem is in the receiving part.

Comment: ((System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders)(response.RequestMessage.Content.Headers)).ToString()

returned:
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 247

Comment: OK, so time to debug your server code. The problem doesn't seem to be on the client. You could use Fiddler to replay the same request and put breakpoints in the server side action to see why it crashes.

Comment: THANK YOU for sharing this! I needed the encoding for this work for the server to accept it.